# Does IBM API Connect support multipart/form data content type for handling attachments?

Tags: api, websphere, attachment

Does IBM API Connect support multipart/form data content type? I am trying to build a passthrough API where we can publish APIs with GET and POST to retrieve or upload attachments. The attachment does not need to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Not by default but you can parse by hand the payload like in the following link:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/support-web-form-api-connect-post-http-requests-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-and-multipartform-data-content-types

```
var bodyAsBlob = apim.getvariable("request.body").item(0);
var bodyAsString = bodyAsBlob.toBuffer().toString();
var parameters = bodyAsString.split("&");
for (var i = 0 ; i < parameters.length ; i++) {
     var parameter = parameters[i].split('=');
     var parameterName = decodeURIComponent(parameter[0]);
     var parameterValue = decodeURIComponent(parameter[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, my API does not need to parse the attachment. It needs to send it to the backend/provider system as it is. Can I use both GET/POST in that case?

Comment: I would swear you can and it would look like an uncomplete API if it would'nt allow you, but I can not try it myself with the current amount of work :(